# Google Cloud - gcloud script using startup script stored on Cloud Storage

Tags: powershell, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

In GCP cloud I would like to deploy and then configure Windows Server using gcloud startup script. I have PowerShell script (for Windows Server configuration) prepared and tested. I have uploaded this PowerShell script into Cloud Storage. I have prepared gcloud command script for VM deployment (gcloud command script I have saved as a .sh script). I uploaded this .sh script into the Cloud Shell. In .sh script I am using metadata startup script section`--metadata=startup-script-url="gs://bucketName/Server-Configuration-Script.ps1`. in `Server-Configuration-Script.ps1` PowerShell script I have 4 parameters that I have to pass, below srcipt params.

```
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string] $paramA,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string] $paramB,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string] $paramC,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string] $paramD
 )
```

My question is how can I use all four parameters in a startup script section `--metadata=startup-script-url="gs://bucketName/Server-Configuration-Script.ps1` in my .sh script?

Comment: Do you know the param before starting the VM?

Comment: Yes, but i dont want to use values hardcoded im powershell script.

Comment: I personally prefer the Compute Engine custom metadata instead of hardcoding value. That let you more flexibility and the capacity to reuse the same script on other VM without changing the content of the script. Any reason for hardcoded the value? Will you use the same script on other VM with different parameters?

Comment: As I mentioned I am not going to use hardcoded values. In my PowerShell code stored in the Cloud Storage bucket I have four params, listed above in the post. in my cloud shell gcloud command I want to use metadata section `--metadata=startup-script-url="gs://bucketName/Server-Configuration-Script.ps1 -paramA -paramB -paramC -paramD`, but I am nor sure how to create this command, how to pass parama paramA...D.

Comment: If you pass a startup script url, you can't provide parameters. That's why you need to provide them elsewhere, in metadata for example

Comment: So can you give me example hoi it should like, I mean the meta data command I have to put in the cloud shell gcloud command script?

Comment: My gcloud metadata section now looks like this, and it does not work as expected, VM has been deployed, but Server is not configured by Powershell script. meta data section --> `--metadata="startup-script-url=https://storage.cloud.google.com/bucketName/Server-Configuration-Script.ps1,ParamA=4,ParamB=25,ParamC=1,ParamD=Windows Server 2016"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to set, in the metadata of the VM the value of your parameters.

```
gcloud compute instances add-metadata instance-name \
    --metadata ParamA=4,ParamB=25,ParamC=1,ParamD="Windows Server 2016"
```

Then, in the startup script, you can get them like this

```
paramA=$(curl http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/attributes/ParamA -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google")
```

---

**EDIT 1**

After test on a windows machine, I found how to do at startup

```
Invoke-RestMethod -H @{'Metadata-Flavor'='Google'} -Uri 'http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/attributes/ParamA'
```

Curl is an alias of `Invoke-WebRequest` that requires a first initialization, for the current user, of Internet Explorer configuration. When you run the startup script it runs as System account and you didn't configure IE for this user.

*I'm not good in powershell. The command works when I redirect the output to a file, like `> c:\Windows\Temp\paramA.txt`. Adapt the code to a better PS script than I can do!*

Comment: So You are suggesting to put  this curl request -->  `paramA=$(curl http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/attributes/ParamA -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google")` into my startup PowerShell script?

Comment: Yes, instead of expecting external parameter, to initialise them at the beginning of the script

Comment: I used params as you mentioned in the startup PowerShell script --> `$ParamA=$(curl http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/attributes/ParamA -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google")`. Unfortunately that solution does not work, VM is still not configured after deployment :( This is not a linux VM but Windows one, I think there is no curl soft installed.

Comment: I can use CURL on my windows workstation with PowerShell and I though it was the same on the GCE.

Comment: I have tested the same solution on Windows Server 2019, on this OS curl is installed, but the result is the same, VM is deployed but not configured.

Comment: Hi, any other ideas hiw to resolve this problem?

Comment: I tested a solution that worked for me in startup script (Note: we won't be friends; I don't like windows and I had to deep dive in Powershell for you!! :) :) :) :) )

Comment: Hi  guillaume blaquiere, I have just tested new solution, as per Your recommendation. I have uploaded .ps1 file into Cloud Storage. In cloud shell script put 'gcloud compute instances add-metadata instance-name \
    --metadata ParamA=4,ParamB=25,ParamC=1,ParamD="Windows Server 2016"'. In Powershell configuration script I prepared all params like here --> '$ParamA = Invoke-RestMethod -H @{'Metadata-Flavor'='Google'} -Uri 'http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/attributes/ParamA''. Once deployment is completed, I logged on to VM, but server is still not configured.

Comment: I tested command from VM, Powershell console ''Invoke-RestMethod -H @{'Metadata-Flavor'='Google'} -Uri 'http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/attributes/ParamA'' and I was able to see the correct parameter/output. Server has a firewall rule egress 443, 80 to 0.0.0.0/0. It looks that script has not been downloaded to VM. is there any steps required to perform?

Comment: OK, I have corrected my metadata section in a gcloud command and now it worked, Thanks!